Raspberry pi OS safety online on raspberry pi 5 8GB
I installed the Raspberry Pi OS with Raspberry Pi Imager on my rasp 5 8gb and was surprised that sudo doesn't require entering password by default, the OS will also boot into desktop without any user password required by default.
Is the Rasp OS inherently insecure and not meant to be used as a NAS connected to the internet? If NOT then what more changes need to be done to the system so it is considered safer on par with other linux OSs ? (besides sudo behavior and auto login)
Previously I would have raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu server and xubuntu desktop but xubuntu won't run on Rasp 5, so I installed Rasp OS instead.

I'd guess those defaults are targeted at beginners learning how to use the technology.

what changes need to be done to the system - disable auto login, disable no password for sudo

You have obviously done no research. There is a menu to enable boot options and only the primary (admin) user has passwordless login by default and how to change is well documented on this site.

How does that relate to my question on other (if any) changes needed to be made to make it more secure on par with other OSs? You are saying what I know already and I'm not asking about.

To fix the auto-login into a GUI interface, use the raspi-config interface. (kalipi-config on Kali for some reason)
There is a GUI for it in the desktop interface, or you can use a terminal and run sudo raspi-config. Use the arrow keys to navigate the menus.
As for the no-password-for-sudo thing, this is only  for the default user (and root perhaps...). If you don’t like that, use a different user, and make a really hard password for the default user so that nobody can compromise your system with it. Or you could try to mess around with UNIX groups, maybe there’s an ‘admin’ group or something.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
